Is my approach correct for this task?
In this circuit, we're using a non-inverting amplifier. I need to determine the output voltage (V(OPV+)) and the voltage gain (Ak). First, I calculated the total resistances for R1 and R2, as well as for R3 and R4. We can refer to these resistances as R12 and R34, respectively. R12 is the sum of R1 and R2 because they are connected in series, while R34 is the combined resistance of R3 and R4, which are connected in parallel. This approach simplifies the problem. The voltage gain Vk can be derived from the formula 1 + (R34/R12), and the output voltage V(OPV+) is obtained by multiplying Vk with the input voltage V(E).

"R3 and R4, which are connected in parallel" No, they're not. In any case, the ratios of R1 to R2 and R3 to R4 are what set the gain, not the total values.

You don't say why you did those calculations, and how you ended up with the result. But safe to say, the approach seems completely random to me.

@Finbarr: Do you mean that A(k)=1+(R1/R2)/(R3/R4)?

No. R1 with R2, and R3 with R4 form two potential dividers.
